# Data getting deleted on logging in again after logout using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

This is my firebase google login.. i want to add the information of username and email to be saved in firebase realtime database.. so i added the put method.. but this is not working as i expected. everytime i logout and login with the same google acoount all my other data under the userID get deleted eventhough the data are in other nodes. 
[image]

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        String userName = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                        String userEmail = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                        Map newPost = new HashMap();
                        newPost.put("userName", userName);
                        newPost.put("userEmail", userEmail);
                        current_user_db.setValue(newPost);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // updateUI(null);
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whet you are using the 'setValue' method, its overright all the data, try to use updateChildren instead,

full code:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    String userName = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                    String userEmail = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                    DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                    Map newPost = new HashMap();
                    newPost.put("userName", userName);
                    newPost.put("userEmail", userEmail);
                    current_user_db.updateChildren(newPost); // This is the important line
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // updateUI(null);
                }
                // ...
            }
        });
```

}